# Generated wrong namespace

Tags: xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

Is it possible that the namespace you declare will change if you generate an output? Is it because it gets the last version of this schema?

Below are the namespaces in my schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25" targetNamespace="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

and the output generated was like this:

```
<gl-cor:defter xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12 gl-cor-content-2006-10-25.xsd">
```

if you notice that the namespace of xmlns:gl-cor in the output was changed to "http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12". I've checked all my files and there's no 2010-04-12 declared. Anyone knows the reason why it happened?

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12" xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2006-10-25" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">



<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/gl-cor:defter">
    <edefter:defter xmlns:edefter="http://www.edefter.gov.tr" 
                          xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
                          xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
    </edefter:defter>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/gl-cor:defter/gl-cor:xbrl">
        <xbrli:xbrl 
                            xmlns:iso639="http://www.xbrl.org/2005/iso639" 
                            xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" 
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                            xmlns:gl-plt="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/plt/2006-10-25"
                            xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xbrli:xbrl>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::gl-cor:entityInformation]">
    <xsl:element name="gl-bus:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />       
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[self::gl-cor:creator]">
    <xsl:element name="gl-bus:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />       
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my xml input file:

```
<gl-cor:defter xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2010-04-12 gl-cor-content-2006-10-25.xsd"><gl-cor:xbrl><gl-cor:accountingEntries><gl-cor:documentInfo><gl-cor:creator contextRef="ledger_context"></gl-cor:creator><gl-cor:entityInformation><gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber><gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription contextRef="ledger_context"></gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription>
```

Comment: Check your XSLT, you should have done something there that does this. If you can't find the problem, share your XSLT and your input XML

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT just copies the input to the output (the first template is an identity transformation).

Since the namespace mappings for the prefix `gl-cor` are different in the XSLT and the XML input file, none of the other templates will match.